# DynamoDB mapper class missing in dynamodb client

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use dynamodb client by declaring following artifacts in my project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodbmapper-v1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Both of the above jars not contain classes related to dynamodb.

But if see the artifacts downloaded by using following GAV then i see the classes in extracted jar.

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
```

Whats the difference between group com.amazonaws and software.amazon.awssdk and where is there a difference?
Why is the mapper missing in the first GAV.

Amazon mentions following in the first artifact

```
 <artifactId>dynamodbmapper-v1</artifactId>
    <name>AWS Java SDK :: Test :: Amazon DynamoDB Mapper v1</name>
    <description>DynamoDB Mapper largely unchanged from v1. The v1 Mapper is kept for testing purposes only. All classes are in the test directories to prevent use in application code.</description>
    <url>https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava</url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like the amazon documentation - I'm not sure if this is your case but, for me, most of the time the material there is outdated.

I'm using the aws client and the Lavelle community dynamo library to make some queries into DynamoDB via annotations / querydsl.

Below follows my pom.xml for a spring-boot/spring-data/dynamodb/swagger micro service.
I hope it helps.

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sandbox-aws-DynamoDB</groupId>
<artifactId>sandbox-aws-DynamoDB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sandbox-aws-DynamoDB</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <spring-boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

    <!--
    Spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE DOES NOT WORK WITH spring-data-dynamodb 5.0.0
    missing org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslUtils
    -->
    <spring-data-dynamodb>4.5.0</spring-data-dynamodb>
    <aws-java-sdk-dynamodb>1.11.136</aws-java-sdk-dynamodb>

    <log4j.version>1.3.8.RELEASE</log4j.version>

    <swagger2.version>2.7.0</swagger2.version>
    <swagger.ui.version>2.7.0</swagger.ui.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AWS DynamoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-dynamodb}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk-dynamodb}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>sandbox-aws-dynamodb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
                        <docletPath>/home/jorge/project/umlgraph-5.6.6.jar</docletPath>

                        <docletArtifact>
                            <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
                            <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
                            <version>5.1</version>
                        </docletArtifact>
                        <additionalparam>-views</additionalparam>
                        <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```